# Is there a linux-compat tex editor that runs side-by-side?

Tags: editors

I'm writing my dissertation and would like to be able to work on several chapters simultaneously.  I noticed one can do split-editing in UltraEdit:

http://www.ultraedit.com/support/tutorials_power_tips/ultraedit/vertical_horizontal_split_editing.html

But this doesn't seem possible in TexMaker or TexStudio.  Are there any Tex editors that would allow for this that you can recommend?

Thanks

Comment: You mean like `vim`?

Comment: emacs has a multi-window mode.

Comment: I'd prefer, if possible, to use something less hardcore than vim and emacs.  Sorry, I am just spoiled. Something designed for TEX, and noob-friendly like TexStudio

Comment: Lots more Linux-specific suggestions at [What LaTeX Editor do you suggest for Linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1235043)